# How do I edit a telegram message multiple times?

Tags: python, python-3.x, telegram-bot, python-telegram-bot

Hi I'm trying to make a telegram bot that edits its same message multiple times like BotFather does, but every time that I try it gives me this error:

```
telegram.error.BadRequest: Message is not modified: specified new message content and reply markup are exactly the same as a current content and reply markup of the message
```

Here is the code, I tried to make it as clear as possible.

```
from telegram import InlineKeyboardButton, InlineKeyboardMarkup
from telegram.ext import *
from API import API_KEY
from bot_messages import *


updater = Updater(API_KEY, use_context=True)
dispatcher = updater.dispatcher


def start(update, context):
    update.message.reply_text(WELCOME, reply_markup=InlineKeyboardMarkup([[InlineKeyboardButton("Ciao", callback_data="ciao")]]))

def ciao(update, context):
    update.callback_query.edit_message_text("Ciao", reply_markup=InlineKeyboardMarkup([[InlineKeyboardButton("Dona!", callback_data="donate")]]))

def donate(update, context):
    update.callback_query.edit_message_text("Dona", reply_markup=InlineKeyboardMarkup([[InlineKeyboardButton("Dona", callback_data="dona")]]))


dispatcher.add_handler(CommandHandler("start", start))
dispatcher.add_handler(CommandHandler("restart", start))

dispatcher.add_handler(CallbackQueryHandler(ciao))
dispatcher.add_handler(CallbackQueryHandler(donate))


updater.start_polling()
updater.idle()
```

Also can you tell me the proper way of making inline query handlers? Because if it is giving me error it could perhaps mean that I'm not doing it quite right. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your snippet only the first `CallbackQueryHandler` will ever handle updates - please see the docs of [`Dispatcher.add_handler`](https://python-telegram-bot.readthedocs.io/en/stable/telegram.ext.dispatcher.html#telegram.ext.Dispatcher.add_handler) for details on how dispatcher decides which handler gets to handle an update.
That's why your code is trying to update the message with the unchanged text and you get that error.

To fix that, you can e.g. use the `pattern` argument of `CallbackQueryhandler`.

---

Disclaimer: I'm currently the maintainer of `python-telegram-bot`.

Comment: Thanks man this fixed everything. Keep up with the work bro!